# Core Location not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, core-location

When I enter the following code and run it on the simulator and set the location to "City Run", it does not log anything. I don't know what I am doing wrong though.

.h

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locMgr;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locMgr;
@property NSInteger speed;
```

.m

```
@synthesize locMgr;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.locMgr = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locMgr.delegate = self;
    self.locMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    self.speed = roundf([newLocation speed]);
    NSLog(@"speed: %ld", (long)self.speed);
}
```

Do you see anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key, to your info.plist

Comment: That and I also added `[self.locMgr requestWhenInUseAuthorization];`

Comment: Have you tried using a different location, such as Apple. Or run it on an actual device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request authorization to use location services using either:

```
[self.locMgr requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

or

```
[self.locMgr requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```